# Page Transition is not working specifically scale or fade functions

Tags: flutter, mobile

I am using animated splash screen, but my page transition does not working.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return AnimatedSplashScreen(
  splash: Image.asset(
      'lib/logo/MedicteLogo-4a2e31cd2358bb08ff8d12acb2761357.png'),
  nextScreen: HomePage(),
  splashTransition: SplashTransition.scaleTransition,
  pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.topToBottomJoined,
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try import this code. I succeeded after importing the code

```
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same problem here **"PageTransition"** is not working at all, after duration of splash screen finishes it removes splash screen without an **PageTransition** and shows next screen.
I think it has something to do with my Android version which is **Android 12**